# How to rotate collection instance with reference point

Tags: transform-orientation

I have a question concerning precision edition of a geometry.

Here I'm simply trying to align a window collection instance with a given axis.

Logically, with a pivot set to the instance's origin P0, I would like to select P1 and then P2 to match edge [P0 P1] with [P0 P2].

Actually I can snap on P2 but geometry just tries to ture 90 degrees.

Does anybody has a solution for this?

p.s. Please concern that solution has to be made without manipulating original collection itself. Just think about placing identical windows along walls that doesn't go parpendicullarly.

Happy blending!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first job is to get the origin of the Collection Instance in the right location and orientation with respect to its component objects.

When a Collection Instance is created, all its component objects retain their World Transforms, with respect to the collection's origin (represented by an Empty). While you *can* move the origin of a collection using the Header > Object > Set Origin menu, it's probably least confusing to keep the Collection origin *at* the world origin while assembling. You can hide the source collection, and still work with its instances.

Once that's done, you can align the instance as you would any other object. (You can search for various ways besides this to do that, here on BSE)

[image]

Here, the original collection is shown at the origin, as created. In this example..

- A Custom Orientation was created from the sloping target face. (The '+' in the Orientation dropdown)
- The 3D Cursor was snapped to the face (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>)
- The (wireframe) Instance was snapped to the cursor (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>)
- With the instance selected, and the Custom Orientation active, Header > Object > Transform menu, 'Align to Transform Orientation'

You can align multiple instances in one move.

The Instance's local axes are shown in the gizmo.

Comment: Thank you so much. Always surprised how blender community is supportive to a newbe like me.

Answer (score 1):

You can snap the rotation without modifying the origin point.
While not not as elegant as @Robin Betts's answer, it's fast :).

1. Enable snapping to *Face* and check *✓ Align rotation* and  *✓ Project elements*
2. Drag the rotate tool *anywhere* in the 3D viewport, it will snap (but with the wrong face)
3. Correct the rotation in the sidebar, so it's only rotated on the Z axis

[image]

*Note:*
If nothing else, this method will give you the exact angle, so you can enter it manually into whichever axis you want :).

Comment: Yours is just as elegant.. and OP could construct the instance to be the right-side-out.. I was going for centering to the face, too, but maybe that's surplus.

Comment: Nah, the more I play with it, the less it works :). The custom orientation is way more practical.

Comment: gif is always awesome! Thank you for the kind response.

Comment: Just now I've tried it and works perfectly. The thing now concerns me is the meaning of those options. I think I understand align rotation to target - it means object will be rotated to match it's z-axis with target's z-axis right? But what 'Project individual object I do not understand. Orienting in blender is still kind of confusing. Can you recommend any text or video resource exploring advanced transformation system of Blender?